# Image in PDF Report using wkhtmltopdf on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I want a PDF report with image in record.

the html report works fine with below code:

```
<% if @student.photo.file? %>
        <%= image_tag @student.photo.url %>
  <% end %>
```

but when I try pdf report with following code it doesnt work. pls help.

```
<% if @student.photo.file? %>
        <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag @student.photo.url %>
   <% end %>
```

and this is my def in controller

```
def generate_id_card
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    render :pdf=>'generate_id_card',
    :show_as_html => true
```

`which wkhtmltopdf` shows nothing but I have it installed in `/opt` directory at: `/opt/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`

and the WickedPdf.config is

```
WickedPdf.config = {
#    :wkhtmltopdf => '/opt/wkhtmltopdf',
    :wkhtmltopdf => '/opt/wkhtmltopdf-amd64',
    :layout => "pdf.html",
    :margin => {    :top=> 40,
                    :bottom => 20,
                    :left=> 30,
                    :right => 30},
    :header => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_header.html'}},
    :footer => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_footer.html'}}
```

---

which wkhtmltopdf
show nothing but I have it installed in /opt
/opt/wkhtmltopdf-amd64

and the WickedPdf.config is

```
WickedPdf.config = {
#    :wkhtmltopdf => '/opt/wkhtmltopdf',
    :wkhtmltopdf => '/opt/wkhtmltopdf-amd64',
    :layout => "pdf.html",
    :margin => {    :top=> 40,
                    :bottom => 20,
                    :left=> 30,
                    :right => 30},
    :header => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_header.html'}},
    :footer => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_footer.html'}}
```

Comment: Try to use ` :show_as_html => true` option with render_from_string

Comment: Thanks dear it worked, but I dont know how to print it now? bcoz the output is simple html not pdf

Comment: paste the code in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rendered_id_card = render_to_string(:template => "students/generate_id_card.pdf.erb", :show_as_html => true )
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string rendered_id_card
```

try this

Comment: try ` which wkhtmltopdf` in your command prompt. It will give you path of wkhtmltopdf. Paste that path in config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb and restart your server